# Does data frame row and column contains string? If so, return that string in new column

Tags: python, dataframe, transformation, contains, data-processing

I have a Data frame and I want to create a new column that is- if a string exists in a specific column then output that string as the value for the new column plus 3 number of spaces after that.

Example-

In this example I would want to search for the string "Note" and if that string exist in the column note, then put "Note" and what ever is in the next three spaces after that.

Before:

| id | partNumber | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1b33 | apples |
| 2 | hhgh5667 | banana, Note 55, and pineapples |
| 3 | hhgh5667 | Note 1A, and blueberries |
| 4 | 09890ii | blackberries |

After:

| id | part_number | note | Note_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1b33 | apples | NA |
| 2 | hhgh5667 | banana, Note 55, and pineapples | Note 55 |
| 3 | hhgh5667 | Note 1A, and blueberries | Note 1A |
| 4 | 09890ii | blackberries | NA |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with `str.extract` to capture everything from Note to just before the comma.

```
df['Note_number'] = df.note.str.extract('(Note.*)(?=\,)')
```

Output

```
   id partNumber                             note Note_number
0   1      a1b33                           apples         NaN
1   2   hhgh5667  banana, Note 55, and pineapples     Note 55
2   3   hhgh5667         Note 1A, and blueberries     Note 1A
3   4    09890ii                     blackberries         NaN
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! What does '.*' and '(?=\,)' mean? Also, is there a way to pull multiple notes if the string 'Note' appears more then once in the note column?

Comment: I'm sure you can, just need to modify the regular expression, https://regex101.com/r/zUOzJe/1